# Remove text after a specific word except certain characters in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

First post: Let me know if I'm posting in the wrong place.
I'm looking to remove text from a lot of data i R.
Each line(string?) looks like this:

```
example_sentence <- "John Doe and Jane Doe (C)"
```

I would like to keep only the first name in every sentence and the parenthesis (including what's in it).
Every parenthesis contains one or two letters (both in capital and lower case letters)

What I've tried:

```
example_sentence %>% str_remove("and.*")
```

This obviously removes the parenthesis. Just getting to know regexpr. Looking for something like:

```
[^(*)]
```

Can't get it to work. Any thoughts?

EDIT:
Here's some more input as requested. Maybe it will help others! (och = and in Swedish)

```
[1] "Anders Ahlgren och Anders Åkesson (C)"           
[2] "Karin Nilsson (C)"                               
[3] "Edward Riedl (M)"                                
[4] "Per-Ingvar Johnsson och Anders Åkesson (C)"      
[5] "Per-Ingvar Johnsson och Annika Qarlsson (C)"     
[6] "Annika Qarlsson och Ulrika Carlsson i Skövde (C)"
```

Expected output:

```
[1] "Anders Ahlgren (C)"           
[2] "Karin Nilsson (C)"                               
[3] "Edward Riedl (M)"                                
[4] "Per-Ingvar Johnsson (C)"      
[5] "Per-Ingvar Johnsson (C)"     
[6] "Annika Qarlsson (C)"
```

Comment: Mybe `"\\band\\b[^()]*"`?

Comment: Please include few more example in the post and show expected output for the same.

Comment: Thanks! Added more input/output. And also solved it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[^(*)]` pattern matches any single character but `(`, `*` and `)` and `str_remove` removes all these characters from anywhere in the string.

If you plan to remove a word `and` and any chars other than `(` and `)` after it, you may use

```
 example_sentence %>% str_remove("\\band\\b[^()]*")
```

Or, using base R:

```
sub("\\band\\b[^()]*", "", example_sentence)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\band\b` - a whole word `and` (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `[^()]*` - any char, 0 or more occurrences, other than `(` and `)`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2ngtC/2) and an [R demo](https://ideone.com/yQ91Id). See also the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cband%5Cb%5B%5E()%5D*):

[image]

Comment: Well explained!

Comment: Your str_remove line did the trick perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
example_sentence <- "John Doe and Jane Doe (C)"

spliting <- function(x)
{
  y <- strsplit(x,split = ' ')
  z <- y[[1]]
  z <- z[c(1,length(z))]
  return(z)
}

spliting(example_sentence)

[1] "John" "(C)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with capture groups. As Ronak says, a few more example input/outputs would be helpful as I'm not sure we know 100% all the possible forms you have in your data.

Here is a start in any case:

```
gsub('and.*(\\([^)]*\\)).*', '\\1', example_sentence)
# [1] "John Doe (C)"
```

Comment: Try it with `Roland Doe (c)`.